# How to have an output based on an uploaded csv file with the packages Flask?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, flask

My goal is to have a Flask app who let the user put a csv file and the app return an specific output.

Here's the output I want, let me show you how I done it in jupyter notebook :

```
for i in df['variable1'].unique():
    
    data = df[(df['variable1']  == i)]
    
    data['list'] = data['comms_clean'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split())

    top = Counter([item for sublist in data['list'] for item in sublist])

    mostcommon = pd.DataFrame(top.most_common(3))
    mostcommon.columns = ['Common Word', 'Count']
    print()
    print('For the classe "{0}" who appears {1} time, here is the 3 most frequent word: '.format(i, data.shape[0]))
    print()
    print(mostcommon.head(3))
    print()
```

And here's the result :

```
    For the classe "classe1" who appears 389 time, here is the 3 most frequent word: 
    
      Common Word  Count
    0  word10       267  
    1  word20       149  
    2  word30       46   
    
    
    For the classe "classe1" who appears 657 time, here is the 3 most frequent word: 
    
      Common Word  Count
    0  word40       234  
    1  word50       89   
    2  word60       34   
    
    
    For the classe "classe3" who appears 250 time, here is the 3 most frequent word: 
    
      Common Word  Count
    0  word70        90   
    1  word80        30   
    2  word90        19   

...
```

But I cannot figure it out how to transpose this into Flask.

Here's my `app.py` :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import pandas as pd

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'csv', 'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads/'
    

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file(filename=None,column=None, data=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        render_template('index.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash("No file part")
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash("No selected file")
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter = ';')
            column = list(df)
            data = [list(df[d]) for d in column]
            df_head = df.head()
            

            return render_template('index.html', data=data, tables=[df_head.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)

    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here's my `index.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Upload File</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% if data %}
    {% for table in tables %}
        {{titles[loop.index]}}
        {{ table|safe }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But this app give me the `head()` of the csv file uploaded, the specific output I want is way harder to implement so if you could help me, it would be awesome.

I think I need to create a dataframe with my most frequent word because Flask seems to need a dataframe but I'm not entirely sure.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is sample csv you are uploading? What is the output? What is the output do you want to see?

Comment: My csv file is just a csv with one variable text and one variable with classes. I put in my post the output I made (in jupyter notebook) and this is the output I want to see but in Flask.

Comment: For debug purposes, just return string instead of rendering and check if your output is correct. If it is correct check your render function with html file

Comment: string instead of rendering ? Coud you explain more in details ?

Comment: you used `df_head = df.head()` thats why it gives its head

Comment: I know.. That's not my problem.. I would like to have another output, not understand why I have `head`

Comment: Then you should integrate your algorithm, just paste your jupyter code to flask code

Comment: The problem is taht my algorithm return a `print()` or Flask need a dataframe in my script.

Comment: just copy function from jupyter to flask code and call from there